# How to get a JSON object from a RESTful api and parse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Now one of my friends designed a set of RESTful APIs. Some of them are 'GET' method and return JSON format data.

And I have to write a html page with some javascript code to get data from his API and parse the data.

When I enter a text and click a button, it will send a GET request to my friend's API server. How to send this request and get this json data from this api and store it in a javascript variable?.

And the format of this json data is like that:

```
[
{
key1 : "value1",
key2 : "value2",
key3 : "value3",
key4 : "value4"
},
{
key1 : "value1",
key2 : "value2",
key3 : "value3",
key4 : "value4"
}
]
```

How to display it on html page in a table with the first row is the name of all keys? And the other rows is all the values?

And can set one value like value4 as a hyperlink where I can click? When I click it, it will create a new page and get something new from the API server?

Comment: Did you even ask Google? There are a zillion answers out there - here's one directly from the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somehow a very long to answer question. I will give you some directions.

take a look at jQuery.ajax() method if you are using jQuery. If not, I recommend you do that.
site is: http://wwww.jquery.com

That will help you make the request and get the data back into a Javascript Object.

Then you can update the DOM which also jQuery is very useful to update or create a table with the data.

Either way, I recommend to check out some MVVM libraries to ease some of the work like Knockout.js or Angular.js

Depending on your skills this might be a little bit 'hard' to get to know, so you can learn jQuery first and manipulate the DOM using it so you can achieve the result you want.